# Two different jars x,y having dependency on different versions of z. How user can have both x,y in his application?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I am making rest client jars to invoke each set of services. For services -1, services -2, services-3; we have respectively clientjar1, clientjar2, clientjar3. In all the rest client jars there are some common functionalities which I have kept in a separate jar i.e in "corejar1.0". All the client jars have dependency on "corejar1.0".

Now I have to create a new client jar "clientjar4" for a new set of services-4. But this wont work with the old "corejar1.0". So I have modified content of corejar and released a new version "corejar1.1". So "clientjar4" refers to "corejar1.1" but all other clients refer to "corejar1.0". Now if a user wants to use both cientjar1 and clientjar4, there will be version conflict bcz they both refer to different core jar version. So one of the client jar might not work as expected.

So one solution is to re-release all the client jars by updating those to point to new "corejar1.1". I feel this is not a good way because we are releasing new versions of client jars although there is no change in their respective services.

My project is a java project and i am using Gradle as a build tool.
Can somebody suggest a better solution ?

Comment: You can use Gradle exclude property to exclude conflicting class.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Andreas, managing the backwards compatibility between `corejar1.0` and `corejar1.1` is your responsibility.

For managing the dependency graph, you rely on the build tool. Gradle in this example will realise that there is a version conflict between `corejar` `1.0` and `1.1` and the default conflict resolution mechanism of Gradle is to pick the highest version.

While this looks like the good solution in your case, there are other cases where it is not that simple. For that you can tweak [the way Gradle will resolve transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html) and their version.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that the changes you made to `corejar1.1` are **backwards compatible** with `corejar1.0`, then having `clientjar1` use `corejar1.1` is not an issue.

It is up to *you* to ensure that shared libraries stay compatible with old "users" of the library, if you want to prevent dependency conflicts.

If you can't make `corejar1.1` backwards compatible with `corejar1.0`, then you must deploy updated versions of all the client jars.

Comment: Core jars are back ward compatible. But user's application has refereed to only clients not the core.. Clients in turn refer the cores. So if there is a situation where user was using cclient jar 1 (which in turn refeers to corejar1.0) and now satrted using clientjar4(Which in turn refers to corejar1.1), then gradle might download corejar1.0 only so functionalities of clientjar4 might not work.

Comment: @smrutiranjan *"Might download corejar1.0 only"?* Did you try it to see what Gradle actually does in that situation, i.e. do a little bit of **research**? Because Gradle will by default resolve the conflict by selecting the *latest* version of the core jar file, as explained in the [answer by Louis Jacomet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53874127/5221149).